# Constructor with optional parameter violates new() constraint

Tags: c#, generics, constructor, constraints

I have a class with this constructor:

```
public Currency(Guid? vcurrencyUI = null)
    : base(vcurrencyUI)
{ }
```

and I want to use this class with a `new()` constraint but I get this error:

> 'Currency' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method ...

If I split the constructor everything works fine:

```
public Currency(Guid? vcurrencyUI)
    : base(vcurrencyUI)
{ }

public Currency()
    : base()
{ }
```

why do I need to split the constructor?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Because a constructor with a default parameter is not a parameterless constructor.

Default parameters are "filled in" by the compiler at compile time. When you write:

```
var foo = new Currency();
```

The compiler generates:

```
var foo = new Currency(null);
```

When the class is compiled, the compiler creates a constructor that takes that `Guid?` parameter, and also generates some metadata that says in effect "if the parameter isn't supplied at compile time, then supply `null`." But no parameterless constructor is generated for the type.

The `new()` constraint requires that a parameterless constructor be defined for the type, and it won't accept a constructor with a single default parameter. Most likely that's because the runtime, which ends up having to call the constructor, doesn't understand the concept of default parameters.

Comment: Jims answer is correct. For a more in depth look at a very similar question see my article here http://blog.coverity.com/2013/09/11/c-bug/

Answer (score 6):

Although Jim [already answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23390461/69809) your question, note that a more general approach might be to allow passing a **delegate** which would instantiate your concrete class, instead of forcing all your implementations to be parameterless.

I.e. instead of this:

```
public class Something<T> where T : new()
{
    public T CreateInstance()
    {
        return new T();
    }
}
```

You can pass an explicit delegate which will do any custom instantiation logic:

```
// note that the constraint is now removed
public class Something<T>
{
    private readonly Func<T> _ctor;
    public Something(Func<T> ctor)
    {
        _ctor = ctor;
    }

    public T CreateInstance()
    {
        return _ctor();
    }
}

// and you can now pass arbitrary constructor logic as a delegate
var x = new Something<Currency>( () => new Currency(null) );
```

This also allows you to create a helper class and have both options readily available:

```
public class Something
{
    // this allows you to use a parameterless ctor
    public static Something<T> Create<T>() where T : new()
    {
        return new Something<T>(() => new T());
    }

    // this allows you to specify a custom one
    public static Something<T> Create<T>(Func<T> ctor)
    {
        return new Something<T>(ctor);
    }
}
```